# JQuery UI - Datepicker - Display date in another element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following code on Codepen.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pnyvG

My aim is to allow users to input their own dates and then it gets outputted into another element in a more readable format e.g. Type date or choose date, and then display date in a paragraph tag in the following format "Wednesday 7th August".

Also, I have a few additional pieces of functionality I require, which would be awesome if someone could give me some direction;

- Once the date is outputted into paragraphs for each input, output the number of nights in between the two dates into another element
- Be able to use the same date picker for both inputs. similar to the behaviour used on the following form; http://www.hipmunk.com/hotels-search

It would great if you guys could help me out.

Thanks in advance,

B

Answer (score 1):

Look [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field) to get you started:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        altField: "#alternate",
        altFormat: "DD, d MM, yy"
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to be limited to input fields. When I change the alternative field to a paragraph is does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the select event of the datepicker, and display the output in your p tag:

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker( {
        onSelect: function(date) {
            // Format and display the date in a p tag
            $('#yourptag').html( $.datepicker.formatDate('dd M yy', date) );
        }
    });
});
```

For finding the date difference, you can refer to: [Find difference between two dates picked from jQuery datepicker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13750250/finding-difference-between-two-dates-picked-from-datepicker-via-javascript)